# How to show directed graph using insight

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am trying to show directed graph using [insights](https://github.com/ignacioola/insights), an interactive force graph written with d3. But I am unable to find any option for that.

Answer (score 3):

I've written this library. There's currently no option to make a directed graph, but i intend to add it in a near future.